# How do i find the number of members of a CNGroup in Xcode 7/ iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, xcode7, cncontact

I want to  display the names of each of the `CNGroups` in an iPhone's contacts database, and the number of people in each group.

I have the array of `CNGroups`, so I can get the name and the identifier properties of each group

I could call

```
[CNContact predicateForContactsInGroupWithIdentifier: theGroup.identifier] ,
```

then create a fetch on the `CNContactStore` using that predicate and then count the number of elements of the array that is returned and that  works.

That seems a long winded and processor intensive way of finding out the number of members, so much so that I'm sure there must be a easier way to achieve this.

Have I missed something or is this the way it has to be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be how I would do it, if you're finding it to be hitting performance you could always dispatch it onto a background queue since according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328)

> this framework is optimized for thread-safe, read-only usage

Comment: no noticeable performance issue - even on main thread on iPhone 5 - data sets shouldn't normally be outrageous large. Also you can do a fetch with a single attribute key rather than have to get and store the entire contact for each contact in the group - it just seems like there should be group.numberOfMembers method in the api